# Re-grouping nodes in variable containing sequence of nodes

Tags: xslt

I am trying to create a two-column print-able HTML phone list from an XML file of organizational groups containing associated personnel

```
 <group print_order=1>
 <group_name><![CDATA[Human Resources]]></group_name>
    <person>...(name, address, phone data)...</person>
    <person> ... </person>
    <person> ... </person>
 </group>
 <group print_order=2>
 <group_name><![CDATA[Operations]]></group_name>
    <person> ... </person>
    <person> ... </person>
    <person> ... </person>
    <person> ... </person>
 </group>
 <group print_order=3>
 <group_name><![CDATA[IT Services]]></group_name>
```

etc.
I'm trying to get to the following html output

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <div class=group>Human Resources
    <person>
     <span class=name> lastname, firstname </span>
     <span class=addr> room# building </span>
     <span class=phone> 555-5555 </span>
    </person>
        (repeated for each person in group)
   </div>
   <div class=group>Operations
    <person>
     <span class=name> lastname, firstname </span>
     <span class=addr> room# building </span>
     <span class=phone> 555-5555 </span>
    </person>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div class=group>IT Services
    <person>
     <span class=name> lastname, firstname </span>
     <span class=addr> room# building </span>
     <span class=phone> 555-5555 </span>
    </person>
        (repeated for each person in group)
   </div>
     etc. 
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<p class=page_break>
<table>  (next table on next page)
 <tr>
  <td>  (next set of groups with people)
  </td>
  <td> ( next set of groups with people )
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
(Repeat tables as needed until all groups output)
```

The problem is that I want the number of lines in a table cell to be less than or equal to the number lines on a printed page, and I don't want groups split across table elements. 
I've tried the xsl:for-each-group instruction, but I can't figure out what the group-by or group-adjacent code should look like. I've also tried the following horrendous test:

```
<xsl:if test="sum($nodes/group[following-sibling::group[preceding-sibling::group[1] is current()]]/@line_count) mod 40 &gt; sum($nodes/group[following-sibling::group[preceding-sibling::group[2] is current()]]/@line_count) mod 40 ">
```

in a `for-each` loop, where nodes is a variable containing the sequence of groups, line_count is the number lines per group, and 40 is the # of lines per page. I'm using HTML tables to maximize browser support.

Is there a better way to do this? Using CSS maybe?  Larry Wall, the author of the Perl language, said that in a programming language, easy things should be easy, and hard things should be possible. Is what I'm after possible in XSLT/XPath? Thanks to anyone willing to wade through all this.

Comment: So, you are searching a way to print (via browser) an html page with tables, avoiding broken tables. So you are trying to minimize the rows of the tables inside each page to the maximum height of the page. Right?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that each person takes a single line, and that no single group is too large to fit on one page. The following stylesheet paginates by recursively collecting groups into a variable (`$currentColumn`) as long as the total number of persons is lower than the desired line count. Columns are collected into another variable (`$columns`) as long as the total number of columns is lower than the desired column count. Once the column limit is reached, a page is output, and then the recursion continues with the next page.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="lineCount" select="25"/>
    <xsl:param name="columnCount" select="2"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:call-template name="paginate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="groups" select="/groups/group"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="paginate">
        <xsl:param name="groups"/>
        <xsl:param name="currentColumn" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="columns" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($groups)">
                <!-- End of input. Print current page and stop recursion. -->
                <xsl:variable name="column">
                    <column><xsl:sequence select="$currentColumn"/></column>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:call-template name="print-page">
                    <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns,$column"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count($currentColumn//person) + count($groups[1]/person) le $lineCount">
                <xsl:call-template name="paginate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentColumn" select="$currentColumn,$groups[1]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="groups" select="$groups[position() gt 1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count($groups[1]/person) gt $lineCount">
                <xsl:message terminate="yes">Too many persons in a group!</xsl:message>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count($columns) + 1 lt $columnCount">
                <!-- Start a new column -->
                <xsl:variable name="column">
                    <column><xsl:sequence select="$currentColumn"/></column>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:call-template name="paginate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns,$column"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="groups" select="$groups"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- All columns full. Print current page and page break, then advance to next page. -->
                <xsl:variable name="column">
                    <column><xsl:sequence select="$currentColumn"/></column>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:call-template name="print-page">
                    <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns,$column"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <p class="page_break"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="paginate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="groups" select="$groups"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="print-page">
        <xsl:param name="columns"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="column/group"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group">
        <div class="group">
            <xsl:value-of select="group_name"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="person">
                <person>
                    <span class="name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
                    <span class="addr"><xsl:value-of select="addr"/></span>
                    <span class="phone"><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></span>
                </person>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @WoodyKellum: Happy to hear it! Since my answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as Accepted?